# how to create wireguard keys solely with php?

Tags: php, key, wireguard

I want to create wireguard private and public keys using solely php as the system i am running the script on is old ( 12.04 ) , for many reasons cannot upgrade it so i am not able to use wireguard utilities like wg genkey.

is there a way for that ? if not php maybe via bash.

Comment: you can' do that, but i found a way to do it with JS instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69088396/how-to-use-getrandomvalues-in-nodejs/69088519?noredirect=1#comment122110690_69088519

Answer (score 0):

I use the `PostLoad` keyword in wg0.conf and run a bash shell to load the private key via `wg set privkey`

Then restart wg-quick service.